# Клиент-сервер с++

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер

Нет обмена пакетами между клиентом и сервером. Помогите!
Вот код клиента:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
int fd;
addrinfo hints,*client,*p;
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = AF_INET;
hints.ai_flags = 0;
char *msg;
char IP[24];
printf("Input IP adress of server\n");
scanf("%s",IP);
if( (getaddrinfo(NULL,IP,&hints,&client)) == -1)
    fprintf(stderr,"Problem with addrinfo\n");
if( (fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == -1)
   {
     fprintf(stderr,"Can't create socket \n");
     exit(0);
   }
 sockaddr_in c;
 c.sin_family = PF_INET;
 c.sin_port = htons(5654);
 inet_aton(IP,&c.sin_addr);
 if ( (connect(fd,(sockaddr *)&c,sizeof(c)))  == -1)
   {
     fprintf(stderr,"Can't connect to server\n");
     exit(0);
   }

while ( recv(fd,msg,300,0) )
    printf("%s\n" ,msg);
if( send(fd,msg,sizeof(msg),0))
    printf("Success!\n");
freeaddrinfo(&hints);
close(fd);
scanf("%i",&fd);
return 0; }
```

Вот код сервера:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<resolv.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>
int main()
{
 struct sockaddr_in sock;
 int fd;
 int sd;
 memset(&sock,0,sizeof(sock));
 char msg[300];
 sock.sin_family = PF_INET;
 sock.sin_port = htons(5651);
 sock.sin_addr.s_addr = 0; //принимаем подключения на все IP
  if((fd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == -1 )
  {
      fprintf(stderr,"Can't open socket\n");
  }
  if ( bind(fd,(sockaddr *)&sock,sizeof(sock)) == -1 )
  {
      fprintf(stderr,"Can't bind\n");
      exit(0);
  }
  listen(fd,0x100);
 sockaddr_in client_addr;
 int client_addr_size = sizeof (client_addr);
 while( (sd = accept(fd,(sockaddr*)&client_addr,(socklen_t*)&client_addr_size)) !=-1 )
 {
    char m[] = "Hello World\n";

   send(sd,m,sizeof(m),0);
   memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));
   recv(fd,msg,300,0);
   printf("%s\n",msg);
 }
 close(fd);
 close(sd);
 scanf("%i",&sd);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: кто вас так учил форматировать код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кхм. У вас сервер и клиент разные порты используют. Скачайте уже наконец Снейдера.

Comment: это пофиксил(забыл вернуть № порта в клиенте к 5651). У меня вопрос : после использования функции accept() для общения с клиентом(чтение пакетов и посылка) мы должны использовать новый дескриптор файла?

Comment: Да; Нужно использовать новый дескриптор. 

Скачайте. Уже. Наконец. Снейдера.